# Labels (annotate) in ggplot2 graphics are not parsed when using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, plotly

I use knitr under Rstudio to produce reports and I have a problem to master the annotations when I use ggplotly.

Hereafter it is an example of code working correctly when I print a ggplot2 graphic with correct annotations, and if I print it with ggplotly I get the correct graphic but with annotations not parsed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly) 

lm_fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
summary(lm_fit)
formule <- sprintf("italic(y) == %.2f % + .2f * italic(x)",
                   round(coef(lm_fit)[1], 2), 
                   round(coef(lm_fit)[2], 2))
r_2 <- summary(lm_fit)$r.squared
r2  <- sprintf("italic(r)^2 == %.4f", r_2)

graph1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', aes(fill = 'confidence'), alpha = 0.5) +
    annotate("text", 
             x=min(iris$Sepal.Width), 
             y=max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
             label=formule, 
             parse=TRUE, 
             hjust=0) +
    annotate("text", 
             x=min(iris$Sepal.Width), 
             y=max(iris$Sepal.Length) - 0.3, 
             label=r2, 
             parse=TRUE, 
             hjust=0) 

out.format <-  "html" # KO for the annotations ; they are not parsed.
out.format <-  "pdf"  # OK for the annotations.

if (out.format == "html") plotly::ggplotly(graph1) else print(graph1)
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly uses HTML formatting tags for its texts.

The following function should take care of that for your example.

```
fix_annotation <- function(old_text){
  new_text = gsub('==', '=', old_text)
  new_text = gsub(' \\* ', '&middot;', new_text)
  new_text = gsub('italic\\(([0-9a-zA-z]*)\\)', '<i>\\1</i>', new_text)
  new_text = gsub('\\^([0-9]*)', '<sup>\\1</sup>', new_text)
  return(new_text)
}
```

The text is added as `scatter` trace with `mode: text` (don't ask why....), so we overwrite the text and fix position.

```
p <- plotly::ggplotly(graph1)
for (i in 4:5) {
  p[['x']][['data']][[i]][['text']] <- fix_annotation(p[['x']][['data']][[i]][['text']])
  p[['x']][['data']][[i]][['x']] <- min(p[['x']][['data']][[1]][['x']]) + 0.1 * (max(p[['x']][['data']][[1]][['x']]) - min(p[['x']][['data']][[1]][['x']]))

}
p
```

[image]